# How to make an API call from micro-service B to micro-service A without authentication

Tags: java, spring, authentication, microservices

The problem which I am facing is that I have a resource known as App in micro-service A, which has had specific roles assigned to it, hence only authenticated users can access this API.

Next, I have a micro-service B, which is an open webhook system, where I am allowing public calls from any unknown source to be accepted.

The webhook micro-service B wants to access the App resource to fetch a particular entity, however since there is an authentication layer to it, I am unable to fetch that resource. I do not wish to open that particular resource over a fixed IP or domain name since it seems a workaround to me.

Is there a better solution to solve this kind of a problem?

Comment: Can’t you make calls from B to A with auth include in it. By any reason, if you open any unrestricted channel at A, There will always a scope of bad entry in it then. Also, if your micro-service is not exposed to outside world then that should be restricted to inside world by all means.

Comment: How do I authenticate a request from B to A? If I generate credentials on B which will have be hardcoded inside the system which developers will be able to access, which becomes a security risk.

Furthermore, the micro-service A is available on the internet, which makes any dev-ops port and IP restriction not possible.